# kex_exchange_identification error when running basic git commands like "git fetch"

Tags: git, github, ssh

I ran the same commands on the same git repos for 2 years, and this error suddenly occurred randomly to me. If I run it multiple times, then sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't

I'm running "git fetch"

```
Fetching origin
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
    
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
error: Could not fetch origin
```

I deleted my .ssh folder and recreated a ssh key in github, but it doesn't help.

Some debug log:

```
ssh -vvv git@github.com
OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

> Hi shengyaliu1212! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

indicates that everything is working just fine.

If everything always works with `ssh` but never, or rarely, works when using an ssh URL with Git, that suggests—though does not in and of itself prove—that the `ssh` command *Git* is running is a different version of ssh than the `ssh` command *you* run.  Check the `core.sshCommand` setting in your Git configuration(s), and/or `GIT_SSH` and/or `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` in your environment.  Be aware that Git-for-Windows comes with a bundled ssh version that is *different from the Windows-provided ssh*, so that's one very easy way to be using two different `ssh`-es.  You can simply use the one that works.

The remaining somewhat-likely possibility is that some middleman (ssh proxy, etc) is interfering in ssh between your system and Git, but this would generally cause all ssh connections to be iffy.  Your `ssh -v` test connection would likely have failed as well.